# Regex help on non-capturing groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Must be a duplication but I can't seem to find it...

I am using a group to match a repeating sub-string. However, I do not want the group to be captured. This seems to be a contradiction.

To be explicit suppose I want to find any character that follows 3 exact replicas of an all capital subset strings. For

```
s = 'hjgABABABfgfBBdqCCCugDDD'
              |         |
```

it should return

```
['f', 'u']
```

I can find very well the repeating strings and following character by

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'([A-Z]+)\1{2}(.)', s))
```

which gives

```
[('AB', 'f'), ('C', 'u')]
```

I can easily parse the resulting list and get just the 2nd items. But is there a regex way to get just the 2nd items to begin with? If I try to do

```
print(re.findall(r'(?:[A-Z]+)\1{2}(.)', s))
```

I get

```
raise source.error("invalid group reference", len(escape)) sre_constants.error: invalid group reference at position 10
```

I'll appreciate a short verification that the issue is indeed a collision between the non-capturing requirement and the capturing that is needed to detect repetitions. Then a clever idea how to achieve the goal neatly.

Comment: With re module, it can't be possible without capturing group. But with `regex` module, it may [possible](https://regex101.com/r/f8Iszd/1)..

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this won't work is that when you write `\1` you basically say "the content of the first group", which is of course undefined if the group is non-capturing.

Answer (score 3):

As [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will always fetch a list of tuples once you define several  capturing groups in the pattern, you can't use "regex-only" approach here.

Use `re.finditer` to get all match data objects and get Group 2 contents from each match only:

```
print([x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r'([A-Z]+)\1{2}(.)', s)])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DliI1e)