# Regex - capture all except character captured by group

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture eveyrthing inside quotes except quote. Examples:

```
'catch this'
"catch this"
'Do not catch this"
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
(\"|\')[^\1]+\1
```

When I did this, it works except last case in examples

```
(\"|\')[^\'\"]+\1
```

Question is, how to capture all characters beside that one captured in the group `\1`. I would like use only regex, I do not want to do processing.
Here you can try it: https://regex101.com/r/iJUeDy/7

Comment: Are you trying to get `[x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r'''(["'])([^'"]+)\1''', s)]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like to use only regex, not loops.

Comment: But is the expected result `['catch this', 'catch this']`? At any rate, **you will have to post-process** your extracted results as `re.findall` always returns all captures (and you can't get rid of a capturing group in this case). You may also get rid of Group 1 (if you prefer `re.findall`) in a similar way, `[x[1] for x in re.findall(r'''(["'])([^'"]+)\1''', s)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for that, however I am interested in regex solution. I am just curious about excluding groups.

Comment: Have you read my comment? It is not possible. And I [already have answered the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654048/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm, I missed that part about impossibility. Well, I need to do that with python post processing, thanks!